# R: rename variable using a function argument

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I would like to use a function in order to calculate a new variable based on existing variables within a dataframe. **The name of the new variable should be defined as a function argument**: e.g. function(df, **varname = "myVarname"**):

```r
calculateTime <- function(df, varname){
 df <- df %>% mutate(varname = end - begin )
 return(df)
}

calculateTime(df, "myVarname")
```

Unfortunately, this code doesn't work.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can change `'myVarName'` string to `df` column hash inside `calculateTime()` function:

```
## some random data ##
df <- data.frame(end = seq(1:10), begin = seq(1:10))

## applying calculateTime() function ##

calculateTime(df, df$varname)
```

Console Output:

```
#   end begin varname
#1    1     1       0
#2    2     2       0
#3    3     3       0
#4    4     4       0
#5    5     5       0
#6    6     6       0
#7    7     7       0
#8    8     8       0
#9    9     9       0
#0   10    10       0
```